# java.util.NoSuchElementException in Java code

Tags: java, exception

**I get this exception:**

```
Please provide width: 4
Please provide height: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at rr.fr.op.lab.prob1.Rectangle.scanner(Rectangle.java:51)
    at rr.fr.op.lab.prob1.Rectangle.main(Rectangle.java:31)
```

**My code is:**

```
package rr.fr.op.lab.prob1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Rectangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {            

        if(args.length != 2 && args.length != 0){
            System.err.println("Invalid number of arguments was provided.");
            System.exit(1);

            double a = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
            double b = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);

            double area = area(a,b);
            double perimeter = perimeter(a,b);

            System.out.println("You have specified a rectangle of width " + a + " and height "
                + b + ". Its area is " + area + " and its perimeter is " + perimeter);
        }

        double x,y,z;
        if(args.length == 0){
            System.out.printf("Please provide width: ");
            x = scanner();
            System.out.printf("Please provide height: ");
            y = scanner();
        }
    }

    private static double area(double a, double b){
        return a*b;
    }

    private static double perimeter(double a, double b){
            return 2*(a+b);
    }

    private static double scanner (){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        double number = sc.nextDouble();
        sc.close();
        return number;  
    }
}
```

After that, I would like to use method trim() to delete whitespaces. Is that possible? And, I need isEmpty() method too. This code must calculate area and perimeter of rectangle. Inputs are form keyboar or command line.

Comment: please, edit this question with proper closing braces.Here see, after System.exit(0); statement if-condition's close bracket need to take place instead of at wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You close the scanner after you use it. This also closes the underlying stream, `System.in` in this case, since it implements `Closeable`.

When you next create a scanner, `System.in` is already closed, so you can't read more elements from it.

Create a single scanner and reuse it multiple times.

---

It is considered a bad practice to close a stream if you didn't open it (or you have potentially leaked the reference).

There may be other code which relies upon the stream being open, so you closing it can lead to failures in that code. Failures remote from the cause like that are notoriously difficult to debug.

Unfortunately, it is very easy to close streams unintentionally, since classes like Scanner, BufferedInputStream etc close their underlying stream when they are closed.

Comment: Can you write me example how to create a single scanner and reuse it multiple times? Thanks!

Comment: It's pretty easy: create the Scanner in your main method, pass it as a parameter to the `scanner()` method, and don't close it at all (see next comment). However, you will probably see that `scanner()` becomes simply a call to `scanner.nextDouble()`, so you may as well just invoke that directly in main.

Answer (score 1):

You can basically pass `scanner` object to your method and close it after you are done with your scanning outside your `scanner()` method.

```
...
if (args.length == 0) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("Please provide width: ");
    x = scanner(sc);
    System.out.printf("Please provide height: ");
    y = scanner(sc);
    sc.close();
}
...

private static double scanner(Scanner sc){
    double number = sc.nextDouble();
    return number;  
}
```

Comment: `x = scanner(sc);` could be `x = sc.nextDouble()`. No need for the extra indirection of a separate method.

Comment: Oops, yes you are right. But we can add exception handling inside scanner method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please provide width: ");
int number1 = 0;
try {
    number1 = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("Please provide height:");
int number2 = 0;
try {
    number2 = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```