# how to use Java7 try-with-resources feature for resources passes as params

Tags: java, try-catch, java-7, try-with-resources

I have seen [java7 try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html).If the closable resources come as params, we need not to declare the resources.For this case how do we use this feature?

```
public static void write(byte[] b, OutputStream os) throws Exception {
    try {
        os.write(b);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Exception in writing byte array");
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if(os != null) {
                os.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Exception while close the outputstream");
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A side-note: Closing the stream is usually the responsibility of the entity that opened the stream. It seems weird that you're accepting an open stream and closing it before you return. (What if I want to use your method to write stuff to a file, then append something else after your content?)

Comment: If you really want to do it this way though, you can simply do `try (OutputStream os2 = os) { ... }`

Comment: In my case, i am sure that I wont append the content after.I wrote this code as a utility method.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it's an internal method or not. It's bad design regardless. If you design it properly, it's evident how to use try with resources: You would simply do `try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("foo")) { write(b, fw); }`.

Comment: I echo what @aioobe says, I have just made the same point here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33117857/3788176 where closing somebody else's stream was the cause of the problem. If you *must* close the stream in that method, I would call the method `writeAndCloseStream` to make it clear what happens to the stream in that method.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply write:

```
static void write(byte[] b, OutputStream os) throws Exception {
    try (OutputStream o = os) {
        o.write(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: if we are doing so, the resource "o" only automatically closed and "os" resource remains open?

Comment: Since `o = os` os is closed because it is the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Once the try block completes it'll call the method `close` to close the resource

```
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.out"))) {
        bw.write("something");
    }
```

resource should implement `Closable` interface